# phpBB3 How can I get the member Names and Avatar pictures outside of the forums

Tags: php, phpbb, phpbb3

I want to be able to show the Members of my forum on my website with their pictures and usernames (or just their usernames). How can I get that info? JSON perhaps? Is there a plugin that could do it or would I need to do a custom MYSQL query to the phpBB database directly?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom mysql query. It's much more flexible that way. [Here's](http://wiki.phpbb.com/Table.phpbb_users) the database structure of `Table.phpbb_users`. You probably need `username` or `username_clean` and `user_avatar`.